# Linq group by collection with where

Tags: c#, linq

I have these structures:
Ticket has a lot of CustomFormFieldItemsInTicket. The relationship is one to many.

And I want to create linq which group ticket by CustomFormFieldItemsInTicket but I want to set which items from the collection will be used.

In sql it is something like this:

```
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM [beta4].[dbo].[Tickets] as t
  INNER JOIN [beta4].[dbo].[CustomFormFieldsInTickets] as cfit
  ON cfit.TicketId = t.Id
  WHERE cfit.CustomFormFieldId = 5 // I set the value
  GROUP by cfit.SelectedCustomFormFieldItemId
```

I tried something like this. But did not work for me.

```
query.GroupBy(gr => gr.ticket.CustomFormFieldsInTicket.Where(wh => wh.CustomFormFieldId == 5).Select(sl => sl.SelectedCustomFormFieldItemId));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but something like this.

```
var query = (from t in gr.Tickets
        join cfit in gr.CustomForm on t.id equals cfit.TicketId
        where cfit.CustomFromFieldId == 5
        group cfit.field by cfit.SelectedCustomFormFieldItemId into g
        select g).ToList() or .Count();
```

Get familiar with using Linq like this. Sometimes using linq like this is useful, sometimes it is not.

Next time though, search a bit more, there are countless topics on this and msdn pages, for example:

[Stackoverflow - Group By Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7325306/2901207)

[MSDN examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545971.aspx)